# CharResponseWrapper captured content is empty

Tags: spring, servlets, servlet-filters

I have tried the following example to replace some content in my servlet response.

[Programming Customized Requests and Responses](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/819-3669/bnagd/index.html)

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
    <link th:href="@{/css/test.css}" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="forbiddenClass">Test!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.css:**

```
.forbiddenClass {
    color: red;
}
```

**CharResponseWrapper.java**

```
public class CharResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private final CharArrayWriter output;

    public CharResponseWrapper(final HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        output = new CharArrayWriter();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return output.toString();
    }

    public PrintWriter getWriter() {
        return new PrintWriter(output);
    }
}
```

**ClassReplacementFilter.java**

```
@Component
public class ClassReplacementFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        final CharResponseWrapper wrapper = new CharResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
        chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);

        String content = wrapper.toString();
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(content)) {
            System.out.println("content is empty for content type: " + response.getContentType());
        } else {
            content = content.replaceAll("forbiddenClass", "correctClass");
            response.setContentLength(content.getBytes().length);
            response.getOutputStream().write(content.getBytes());
        }
    }
}
```

As you might see, I want to replace the string `forbiddenClass` with `correctClass`, but it only works for the html file. The content of test.css does not change and the following message of the filter is printed to output.

```
content is empty for content type: text/css;charset=UTF-8
```

**Why is the content empty for test.css?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Why is the content empty for test.css?*

Because you only captured whatever is written to `response.getWriter()`, not whatever is written to `response.getOutputStream()`.

You need the `HttpServletResponseWrapper` implementation as shown in bottom of this answer to a related question: [Catch-all servlet filter that should capture ALL HTML input content for manipulation, works only intermittently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230602/catch-all-servlet-filter-that-should-capture-all-html-input-content-for-manipula/23381235#23381235).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the solution.